# Capturar valor de td e passar para um form?

Tags: javascript, jquery

como não conheço muito (quase nada de javascript) venho humildemente pedir a ajuda de vocês, eu tenho uma dataTable populada por dados que vem do banco, e quando eu clico em editar abre-se um modal que deve trazer os dados da linha clicada, mais eu não estou conseguindo isto, já tentei de algumas foras aqui, com esplicações que encontrei na internet, mais não consegui sucesso, ajudem, javascript é a melhor solução, se não como fazer isso?

Segue o código da Table

```
                         <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Id</th>
                                            <th>CNPJ</th>
                                            <th style= "white-space: nowrap;">Razão Social</th>
                                            <th>Telefone</th>
                                            <th>Plano</th>
                                            <th style= "white-space: nowrap;">Data da venda</th>
                                            <th style= "white-space: nowrap;">Data da renovação</th>
                                            <th style= "white-space: nowrap;">Valor do contrato</th>
                                            <th style= "white-space: nowrap;">Celular do Gestor</th>
                                            <th>Consultor</th>
                                            <th>Status</th>
                                            <th>Operadora</th>
                                            <th>Editar</th>
                                            <th>Excluir</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody> 
                                        <?php foreach ($clientes as $cliente){?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->id?></td>
                                            <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $cliente->cnpj?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->razaoSocial?></td>
                                            <td style= "white-space: nowrap;"><?php echo $cliente->telefone?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->plano?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($cliente->dataVenda));?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($cliente->dataRenovacao));?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->valorContrato?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->celGestor?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->consultor?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->status?></td>
                                            <td><?php echo $cliente->operadora?></td>
                                            <td><a href="#openModalCliente"><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/editar.png" alt="" width="30" height="30"/></a></td>
                                            <td><a onclick="myFunction()" href=""><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/lixo.png" alt="" width="30" height="30"/></a></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <?php }?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

form

```
            <form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url();?>Cadastros/cadastro_cliente">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="text" name="cnpj" onkeypress="mascara(this, '##.###.###/####-##')" maxlength="18" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input required="true" type="text" value="" name="razao-social" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                     <input required="true" value="" type="tel" onkeypress="mascara(this, '## ####-####')" maxlength="12"  name="telefone"class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="text" name="plano"  class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">Data da Venda
                                                                <input required="true" type="date" value="" name="data-venda" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">Data da Renovação
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="date" name="data-renovacao" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="text" name="valor-contrato" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" onkeypress="mascara(this, '## # ####-####')" maxlength="14" type="text" name="celular-gestor" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="text" name="consultor" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <input required="true" value="" type="text" name="status" class="form-control input-sm">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                                                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                                                <select required="true" name="operadora" class="form-control input-sm">

                                                                    <option value="tim">Tim</option>
                                                                    <option value="oi">Oi</option>
                                                                    <option value="claro">Claro</option>
                                                                    <option value="vivo">Vivo</option>
                                                                </select>
                                                            </div>
                            </div>
                                                 <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                                     <h2 style="color: green"><?php echo $this->session->flashdata("susses");?></h2>
                            </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <input type="submit" value="Atualizar" style="background-color: #106007; font-weight: bold; border-color: #106007;" class="btn btn-info btn-block">

                    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Utilize JQuery que irá facilitar muito

1) Primeiro você deve identificar a linha com o ID para efetuar um consulta posterior

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tr id="tr_' + v_1 + '"></tr>
<table>
```

2) Agora recupere o id da linha para buscar dados e tratá-los em uma função

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#myTable tr').on('click',function(){
            var TrID = $(this).attr("id");

            ////// caso queira fazer com JSON
            $.getJSON('paginacontendoJSONquePodeser.php?id='+TrID, function (data) { 

                alert(data)

                //variáveis
                contador = 1; v_1 = ''; v_2 = ''; v_3 = ''; v_4 = ''; v_5 = ''; v_6 = ''; v_7 = ''; v_8 = '';
                if (data.length > 0) { // verifica se ocorreu resultado
                    // recupera a listagem de dados crie quantos necessários
                    v_1 = data[0].id;
                    v_2 = data[0].razaoSocial;
                    v_3 = data[0].plano;
                    v_4 = data[0].blablablabla;
                });
                    $('#ModalQUEvoceCRIOU #campoDoModal').val('').val(v_2);
                    $('#ModalQUEvoceCRIOU #campoDoModal').val('').val(v_3);
            });
            ///////////////////////////// caso queira fazer com POST
            $.post('paginanormal.php',{ id : TrID },function(data){
                if( data != '' ){

                    // faça um alert para ver o que está trazendo
                    alert(data)

                    //em seguida trate com o quiser os dados
                    $('#ModalQUEvoceCRIOU #campoDoModal').val('').val('faça como mostrado acima');
                }
            });
        });
    });
    // utilize um dos dois modelos ou pelo menos espero ter ajudado você a ter um norte
</script>
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado mesmo valeu,